# ¿Cómo cargar imágenes desde URL de forma asíncrona en las celdas de un UITableView en Swift?

Tags: swift2, asincronismo

Tengo una aplicación con una celda personalizada donde tengo un `UIImageView`, en el metodo `cellForRowAtIndexPath` estoy colocando la imagen pero al correr en el hilo principal traba la aplicación hasta hacer la carga de las imagenes, he intentado hacer una extensión de `UIImageView` pero al momento de correrlo me manda la siguiente excepcion `This application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background thread, which can lead to engine corruption and weird crashes.  This will cause an exception in a future release`

Código:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let celda = self.tableViewImagenes.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("celda", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CeldaImagenCustom

    //Descarga la imagen
    let urlString = lstImagenes[indexPath.row] //Lista con las URLs

    let url = NSURL(string: urlString)!
    let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url)!

    //Coloca el valor de la imagen en el control de la lista
    //celda.imgImagen.imageFromUrl(urlString)    marca error de main thread
    celda.imgImagen.image = UIImage(data: data)

    return celda
}
```

Código de la extensión del `UIImageView`

```
extension UIImageView {
public func imageFromUrl(urlString: String) {
    if let url = NSURL(string: urlString) {
        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
        NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request){data, response, error in
            if let imageData = data as NSData? {
                self.image = UIImage(data: imageData)
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes crearte una función como esta por ejemplo:

```
func asyncImage(urlString: String, completionHandler:(image: UIImage?, url: String) -> ()) {

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), {()in

        if let url = NSURL(string: urlString), let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url), let image = UIImage(data: data) {

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {() in
                completionHandler(image: image, url: urlString)
            })

        } else {

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {() in
                completionHandler(image: nil, url: urlString)
            })

        }

    })

}
```

Aún así, te recomiendo que utilices librerías como [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) (Objective-C) o su versión en Swift [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) que ya incluyen métodos muy eficientes para descargar imágenes en background. Además, están optimizadas para tú caso concreto.